# Mailchimp with Rules

Tags: rules, emails

I installed MailChimp module and i am using Rules module to send emails to subscribed users. For gmail this emails are going in spam. But when i send an email from mailchimp, it's ok, no spam. There are 3 ways i see now -

1. Use rules and fetch subscribed users, then send email to them
   programmaticaly(worst)
2. Configure rules to send emails from mailchimp.
3. Find another way to send emails and not get to spam.

Can i somehow make campaigns for mailchimp and send them with rules automaticaly, or you can suggest another mail module for such task?

Comment: Are you saying that now you are using Rules to send mail *without* using mailchimp, and you just want to use rules to send emails using it?

Comment: that's it. or maybe it's another ways

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure how this works with your setup and Mailchimp, But i have all of my site emails sending through [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/) using the [SMTP Authentication Support](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) module. So far none have been sent to spam.

One thing to note about SendGrid: Their free account sends your emails through a shared IP. Sometimes they can get blacklisted from time to time. But you can eventually purchase a private ip through them to ensure even better spam protection.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Mandrill module to deliver your Drupal email. Mandrill uses the same engine as Mailchimp (although you need a separate account). It will do a much better job of delivering email, and will also let you track bounces, opens and clicks within your email.

Comment: Mandrill now requires a paid Mailchimp account. No longer a standalone product.

Comment: Yes, true. I've since tried Mailgun (Rackspace product, has problems delivering to Office365 and Hotmail/Live accounts - goes straight to junk) and Amazon SES (good but you have to ask nicely to increase your sending limit if you want to send a lot of emails). Also worth noting that Mailgun, SES and Sendgrid all offer API integration as well as SMTP. If you use the API you get better tracking/reporting on the email you send.

Comment: Follow-up up on my comment about Mailgun delivering to junk in Office365. I raised a ticket with the Mailgun support people, and it turns out that some of their IPs are on blacklists due to the behaviour of others sharing that IP. You can see the IP address for each domain in your Mailgun account and then use something like MXToolbox to check for blacklisting. Raise a support ticket with Mailgun if you find that you are, and they'll move you to another IP (and fix the blacklisting on the old IP).